# contain option in a select jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi all I want to empty a select and repopulate after an ajax call

this is my code:

```
(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nation").change(function() {
        var nation_id = $(this).val();
        change_city_by_nation(nation_id);
    });

    function change_city_by_nation(nation_id){
            var site_url_city ="<?php echo(site_url('/backend/city/get_city_by_nation_id')); ?>";
            $.ajax({   
                url: site_url_city, 
                async: false,
                type: "POST", 
                data: "nation_id="+nation_id, 
                dataType: "html", 

                success: function(data) {
                    $('#city').html(data);
                    $('#city').prepend("<option value='0' selected='selected'>All city</option>");

                }
             });
        }
});

 <select name="nation" id="nation" style="width:180px;" >
     <option value="2">Nation2</option>
     <option value="3">Nation3</option>
</select>
<select name="city" id="city" style="width:180px;" >
     <option value="0">All city</option>
</select>
```

It works fine in FF and Chrome, not in Internet Explorer because I think there is a problem of html.
I have tried with:

```
$('#city').empty().append(data);
```

But the problem isn't solved

If I alert data this is my output:

```
<select name="citylist">
<option value="39">Adelaide</option>
<option value="43">Alice Springs</option>
<option value="44">Brisbane</option>
<option value="45">Cairns</option>
<option value="36">Canberra</option>
<option value="31">Darwin</option>
<option value="37">Gold Coast</option>
<option value="32">Margaret River - Regione dei Vini</option>
<option value="40">Melbourne</option>
<option value="41">Palm Cove</option>
<option value="35">Perth</option>
<option value="42">Port Douglas</option>
<option value="33">Sydney</option>
<option value="34">Tasmania</option>
<option value="38">Townsville</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because you are inserting a `<select>` *into* a `<select>`. Remove that element from your response and your code will work fine.

Comment: Great this is the problem, but is possbile to take the option of the select that retrieve to me into data and insert into city?

Comment: Try posting a new question if you can't figure it out, and I'm not sure what you are even asking.